# Insert a numeric value into a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox

I've an assignment for school in which I have to do a basic calculator using JS, but I can't get the result returned into the textbox. Here's my code:

```
    <form>
        <input type="textbox" id="val1"> Primo valore
        <br><br>
        <input type="textbox" id="val2"> Secondo valore
        <br><br>


        <script>      
            function getFloatValue(x) {
                var xf = parseFloat(x.value)
                return xf
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("val1")
            var b = document.getElementById("val2")


            var af = getFloatValue(a)
            var bf = getFloatValue(b)


           function calculate(a,b,op) {
                var r              
                switch (op.value) {
                    case '+': return a+b
                    case '-': return a-b
                    case '/': return a/b
                    case '*': return a*b
                }
            }
        </script>



        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate(af, bf, '+')">
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate(af, bf, '-')">
        <input type="button" value="/" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate(af, bf, '/')">
        <input type="button" value="*" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate(af, bf, '*')">


        <br><br>
        <input type="textbox" id="result" value=''> Risultato
        <br><br>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Resetta tutto">
    </form>
```

I've made lots of tries, but noone of these worked :\

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: What is value of  `af` and `bf` ?

Comment: You're doing a switch on `op.value` but strings have no `value` property. Get rid of the `.value` in your switch.

Comment: @Rayon they are the values of a and b casted to float, appartently a and b had no value because I executed this piece of code before inserting value into textboxes

Comment: @AndrewL. did it, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of passing `variables`, Pass element `ID` attributes so that we can access elements using `id`
- `op.value` does not make sense as you are passing hard-coded `string` for signs

```js
function getFloatValue(x) {
  return parseFloat(x.value);
}


function calculate(a, b, op) {
  var a = document.getElementById(a);
  var b = document.getElementById(b);
  a = getFloatValue(a);
  b = getFloatValue(b);
  var r
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      return a + b
    case '-':
      return a - b
    case '/':
      return a / b
    case '*':
      return a * b
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="textbox" id="val1">Primo valore
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="val2">Secondo valore
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate('val1', 'val2', '+')">
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate('val1', 'val2', '-')">
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate('val1', 'val2', '/')">
  <input type="button" value="*" onclick="document.getElementById('result').value = calculate('val1', 'val2', '*')">


  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="result" value=''>Risultato
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Resetta tutto">
</form>
```

Comment: I've chosen this solution because I didn't really get the other one, but still I've errors:

for '+' I get: 12[object HTMLInputElement]
for others I get: NaN

It's really strange, considering that the code snippet of this solution works fine here :c

Comment: @MC23 — Do compare your code with mine.. I have not used variables as arguments, I have passed `ID`..

Comment: Yeah now it works, I forgot to change b to a after copy part of the code, thank you very much! Accepted this answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation.

Comment: How does this help the OP, who already has a `getFloatValue` function?